# How to change in Javascript the size of a DIV relative to its object inside him?

Tags: javascript, html, object, size

I created a dynamic table that is created according to the number of rows and columns the user inserts.
This is not a TABLE object but simply two for loops.
The higher the number of columns / rows, the higher the DIV, Because if I do not increase the DIV, the lines will shrink and not be created properly.
So basically, how do I change the size of the DIV relative to the object inside it?
Of course I'm talking about an answer to JavaScript.

this is the javaScript + html + css code:
i want to change the mainDiv and the boardDiv sizes Following the rows and columns (which is actually a tribe I created)

```js
var board = document.getElementById('boardDiv');
    var sizePercent;
    var width;
    var height;
    var rowDiv;
    var loadBoard = function() {

            document.getElementById('boardDiv').innerHTML = "";
            createBoard();
    }
    //for the first time the user open the page
    loadBoard();

    function createBoard() {
        width = document.getElementById('width').value;
        height = document.getElementById('height').value;

        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            rowDiv = document.createElement('div');
            for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                var button = document.createElement('button');
                sizePercent = 100/30; //It's a random ratio for every square - do not take it for granted
                    button.style.width = sizePercent + '%';
                    button.style.height = sizePercent + '%';
                    rowDiv.appendChild(button);
                
            }
            board.appendChild(rowDiv);
        }
    }
```

```css
    #mainDiv {
      width : 500px;
      height : 550px;
      border : solid 5px rgb( 112, 146, 190 );
      background-color: rgb( 153, 178, 208 );
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #boardDiv {
      width : 100%;
      height :100%;
    }
    button {
      background: linear-gradient( white, rgb( 72, 109, 159 ) );
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id='mainDiv'>
  <div id='boardDiv'>

  </div>
  <div>
    <form>

      Width:
      <input type="text" name="width" value="10" id="width">

      Height:
      <input type="text" name="hight" value="10" id="height">

      Mines:
      <input type="text" name="mines" value="7" id="mines">

      <input type="button" value="New Game" onclick="loadBoard()">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank's in advance to everyone

Comment: of course we need to see your code

Comment: i edit ny topic and add the code, thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Say somone wants a width of 200 cells and the buttons width is 15px, this will mean that the div needs to be 3000px long (15 * 200). So to resize the div we will use the following command:

```
documnet.getElementById("mainDiv").style.width = button.style.width * width;
```

We will then do the same for the height, say somone wants the table to have a height of 50 and the buttons are 5px tall, this means that the div will need to be 250px tall. We will achieve this by using the following command:

```
documnet.getElementById("mainDiv").style.width = button.style.height * height;
```

This will make the div the exact size needed.